# multiple class inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance

In PHP, is it possible to have multiple inheritance (by the nature of the PHP, not writting modification code)?

For example :

```
class a
{
    public function foo();
}

class b
{
    public function bar();
}

class c extends a, b
{
    public function baz();
}
```

Comment: Here's [a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90982/multiple-inheritance-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90982/multiple-inheritance-in-php

Comment: Might be OT but you can implement multiple interfaces

Comment: And can an interface define a method? I need to have debug methods in all my classes. I also have a DBUser class I want to inherit to provide DB helper functions for classes.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no real multiple inheritance in PHP and thats a good thing.
See the other answers for alternatives.

**Edit:**
By now, PHP supports [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), of which one class can include more than one. They avoid the usual problems of multiple inheritance by throwing an error or requiring you to alias conflicting names.

Comment: Because of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: @Inwdr I don't know if that's an issue as other languages have managed it somehow ... anyway, doesnt matter

Comment: Many other languages have managed it the same way as PHP, they simply don't allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A extends B{

}

class B extends C{

}

class C{

}
```

Comment: This isn't multiple inheritance. It's a subclass of a subclass.