# How can I extend 2 classes in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Inheritance in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90982/multiple-inheritance-in-php)
>   [Can I extend a class using more than 1 class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356128/can-i-extend-a-class-using-more-than-1-class-in-php)

Does anyone know how can I extend 2 classes from one class?

Example:
How can I add another class called classB into the following class?

```
<?php
class Test extends classA
{
   echo "test";
} 
?>
```

I tried the following code, but this is not work:

```
<?php
class Test extends classA, classB
{
   echo "test";
} 
?>
```

Anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

PHP, like Java, does not support multiple inheritance.

Coming in PHP 5.4 will be [traits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which attempt to provide a solution to this problem.

In the meantime, you would be best to re-think your class design. You can implement multiple interfaces if you're after an extended API to your classes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't really support multiple inheritance, but there are some (somewhat messy) ways to implement it.  Check out this URL for some examples:

http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-multiple-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is called "Multiple Inheritance". PHP doesn't support this, however you'd do well to have a read through this StackOverflow thread:

[Multiple Inheritance in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90982/multiple-inheritance-in-php)