# PHP Multiple Inheritance (Inheritance Chaining), Plugins, and Performance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, composition

*Disclaimer:  What you're about to see is unconventional and could cause moderate to severe nausea.*  Keep an open mind.  So many people have been asking about how to do this, and I don't think its necessarily a bad solution.

TL;DR - You could jump down to the **Grand Finale** if you're familiar with `composition` vs `inheritance` and `multiple inheritance`.

I've read a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90982/multiple-inheritance-in-php) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) that suggest `composition` is better than `inheritance`.  I understand that its usually a better approach (and I'm committed to using composition when possible), however lets assume that I'm stubborn and want to attempt multiple inheritance.

**What I'm trying to do:**

```
class A {}
class B {}
class AB extends A, B {} // doesn't work
```

**What actually works:**

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class AB extends B {} // inherits from both A and B
```

I don't mind this, but it won't work for a more modular (plugin) approach (lets say you don't know the names of the classes).  In other words, if I were trying to create an OOP framework that allowed developers to extend a core class multiple times, you'd have to go in and *edit the class definitions* to extend B from A, C from B, and then potentially rename it back to the usable constructor.

**What I'm *REALLY* trying to do:**

```
class DisplayBase {}
class SomePluginDisplay extends DisplayBase {}
class CrazyPluginDisplay extends SomePluginDisplay {}
// ...
class Display extends {LastPlugin}Display {}
```

This is actually possible through the use of

```
eval("class $class_name extends $parent_class_name {}");
```

However, you wouldn't want to put any actual code inside `eval`, so you could use temporary class names.

**Grand Finale**

See: https://gist.github.com/beeblesox/6218135 (also pasted below)

```
class Base {
    function bse(){ echo "base <br />"; }
}

/* You would have to make a dependency-based loader
 * to keep track of class names.  Here, I'm just hard
* coding to show that it could work...
*/
$parent_class = 'Base';
eval("class _BaseA extends $parent_class {}");
class BaseA extends _BaseA {
    function a(){ echo "a <br />"; }
}

$parent_class = 'BaseA';
eval("class _BaseB extends $parent_class {}");
class BaseB extends _BaseB {
    function b(){ echo "b <br />"; }
}

$parent_class = 'BaseB';
eval("class _End extends $parent_class {}");
class End extends _End {
    function nd(){ echo "end <br />"; }
}

$ab = new End();
$ab->bse(); // base
$ab->a();    // a
$ab->b();    // b
$ab->nd();  // end
```

Note:  You can't just eval the first line of the class (without the end `}`).  This is why I used a temporary class to rename them.

The idea here is that there would be a final, blank class that the user would have as a clean slate to add their custom functionality.  And, that final class would override and inherit from the core, and any number of loaded plugins.

**Questions**

I realize that having 1 or 2 (or 10) extra classes in the hierarchy (even though half of them are blank) isn't a great idea.  However, I can't imagine the performance toll would be noticeable.  Could the average page load increase by more than 1%?

As long as there is no user (external) input involved with the `eval` statement, can you see any other consequences?

*Just to reiterate, I've read posts about composition.*  The problem with composition and interfaces, is that they don't allow you to reuse code.  In many circumstances, inheritance provides the fastest, cleanest way to reuse and modify functionality without having to rewrite anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you're looking for [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), introduced in PHP 5.4.0:

```
trait A {}
trait B {}
class C { use A,B; }
```

Comment: I took a look at traits, but I don't know if that's something I want to employ as a standard operating procedure for a framework.

Comment: Allowing multiple plugins to extend a core class is what I'm looking for

Comment: I'd agree that traits are what you're looking for. You may also have a look at Yii's [behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-behavior). It's worth to study the [`CComponent`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/base/CComponent.php) base class, where they utilize PHP's magic methods to make attached behavior methods and properties available from a class.